# Powershell: where {_.Name not in $object}

Tags: powershell, filtering

I'm building a script that lists all Inactive computer accounts. I'd like to exclude a few systems from the results.

I've got a text-file containing all systems to be excluded (one systemname per line). All items are stored in an object with property name "name". So $excluded will contain:

```
name
----
system1
system2
```

To list all inactive systems I use the Search-ADAccount cmdlet:

```
$InactiveComputers = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90 -ComputersOnly | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true}
```

Of course I can loop all results 1 by 1, but is there a simple way to exclude the systems directly from the results? I've got a feeling it's possible with select-object or where-object, but I can't figure out how to compare against the results in an object.

Answer (score 24):

You were basically correct in using this in your title: "where {_.Name not in $object}"

Syntax is a little different. Pipe it to the following

```
Where { !($_.Name -in $excluded) }
```

OR

```
Where { $_.Name -notin $excluded }
```

Both seem to give the same results in the console. Happy coding!

**Note: Tested this on PSv2 and v3.**

I ran across this when looking for an answer and figured I would update with these options for others that run into this.

Comment: What was the $PSVersionTable.PSVersion value of the PSv2 you tested?

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, I was running this on a work laptop which I don't have anymore so I can't say for sure. I don't recall what the exact powershell minor version was. Only recall the major versions. 

I did some digging and found this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx

It shows that Powershell v3 introduces -notin so you would have to use the first method to get this one to work in v2 (  Where { !($_.Name -in $excluded) }  ). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Import the exclude file (as csv) and use the -notcontains operator:

```
$names = Import-csv exclude.txt | Foreach-Object {$_.Name} 

$InactiveComputers = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90 -ComputersOnly | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $names -notcontains $_.Name}
```

Comment: That's not possible: the exclusion file actually also contains comments (= a line starting with a ;) and blanc lines. I don't want them included in my $exclused object.

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question. You could workaround it with: Import-csv exclude.txt | where {$_.Name -match '\S' -and $_.Name -notlike ";*"}

Comment: thanks for the tips. Unfortunately this command returns an empty object. import-csv excluded.txt works. But when I add the foreach or where-statement it returns an empty set

Comment: ignore that last comment. My bad.import-csv combined with where works.

Comment: but infortunately this didn't work. Search-ADaccounts stil includes the excluded items too :(

Comment: Let's make a test, $names = 'sys1','sys2','sys3', do you still get those computers when you run the Search-ADAccount command?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `-notcontains` ([TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692798.aspx)) operator:

```
$InactiveComputers = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90 -ComputersOnly | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $excluded -notcontains $_.name }
```

Comment: sorry, I tried that before, but it's not working. I think this is because $InActiveComputers contains more items (SamAccountName, Name, Enabled, SID, ...) while $Excluded only contains "name". How does where-object know how to match them?